# How Hide columns according to a cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for hidding columns according to a cell value. 
For exemple when the value is 1 the I to BV columns have to be hide. When value is 2 O to BV columns have to be hidding but the I to O columns have to be visible.

My code works only for 1 and I don't find how can I do...
Thank you for your help

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = 1 Then
            Columns("I:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else: Columns("I:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change2(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = 2 Then
            Columns("O:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else: Columns("O:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change3(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = 4 Then
            Columns("U:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else: Columns("U:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change4(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = 5 Then
            Columns("AA:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else: Columns("AA:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change5(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = 6 Then
            Columns("AG:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else: Columns("AG:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change6(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = 7 Then
            Columns("AM:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else: Columns("AM:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change7(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = 8 Then
            Columns("AS:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else: Columns("AS:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change8(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = 9 Then
            Columns("AY:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else: Columns("AY:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change9(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = 10 Then
            Columns("BE:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else: Columns("BE:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change10(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = 11 Then
            Columns("BK:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else: Columns("BK:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change11(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = 12 Then
            Columns("BQ:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else: Columns("BQ:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the columns all in the one sheet? If so, you only need one worksheet change event. At the start of the event unhide all the columns you are working with. Then set up a series of If Target = x  with ElseIf statements that test the value  of Target and hide the respective columns.

Comment: You could indent the code, so it is easier to read. You can use [Rubberduck indentation website](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation). And you can't have `Private Sub Worksheet_Change#number(ByVal Target As Range)` you should add `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` for each Sheet you are using in the workbook. Or/And write all the code on `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` of the desired sheet

Comment: Do you not need anything if the value is `3`?

Comment: @QHarr Yes the columns are all in one sheet. I'm sorry but I don't know what you are talking about.. I'm a noob in excel and VBA...

Comment: @BruceWayne Actually I made a mistake on values. It's 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One change event with multiple conditions tests within an IF statement, using ElseIf. Without writing it all for you, the following it the structure and key elements. There are plenty of examples on stack overflow to help.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then

        'Code to unhide all columns goes here.

        'Then test the contents of B2
        If Target = 1 Then
            Columns("I:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target = 2 Then 
            Columns("O:BV").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target = 3 Then ......'Continue with rest of conditions
        End If
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly !

Answer (score 2):

Just calculate whether the column number is greater than the last column which you want to be visible:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim i As Long
        Dim lastVisible As Long
        'Use cell B2 in the calculation, just in case Target is
        ' something like A1:D17
        lastVisible = 2 + Range("B2").Value * 6
        'That formula is calculating lastVisible such that:
        'If B2 is  1, lastVisible will be  8 (i.e. column H)
        'If B2 is  2, lastVisible will be 14 (i.e. column N)
        'If B2 is  3, lastVisible will be 20 (i.e. column T)
        'If B2 is  4, lastVisible will be 26 (i.e. column Z)
        '... etc, up to
        'If B2 is 11, lastVisible will be 68 (i.e. column BP)
        'If B2 is 12, lastVisible will be 74 (i.e. column BV)

        For i = 3 To 74
            Columns(i).Hidden = i > lastVisible
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in fewer lines:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim primaryCols As Range
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        Range(Columns(3 + Range("B2").Value * 6), Columns(74)).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Range(Columns(9), Columns(2 + Range("B2").Value * 6)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If
End Sub
```

Basically it uses a little arithmetic to get your start column for those you want visible, and end column for those to hide, from column I onward.

Comment: "When value is 2 O to BV columns have to be hidding but the I to O columns have to be visible.", so I think you want to hide **all** the columns, and then just do the one unhide line.  Argh - or is your code back-to-front.  Too early in the morning!!

Comment: Yeah - it should be (a) hide cols 3 to 74 (b) unhide cols 3 to 2+B2*6 - or (a) unhide 3 to 74 (b) hide 3+B2*6 to 74 (with a special test for when B2 is 12)  (Note: `B2` is almost certainly a month number - I'd bet my last dollar on it :D)

Comment: @YowE3K - Indeed, it's too early in the morning/late in the afternoon...OP needs to clarify, he both asks to hide *and* show column O. I can't tell what's to be visible.  ...I'll take another look in a minute.